# Is there a "good" way to visualize complex vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

We often represent complex numbers as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $x$ being the real axis and $y$ being the imaginary axis. We often represent 2-dimensional vectors over $\mathbb{R}$ in a similar way.

Suppose we consider $\mathbb{C}^2$, vectors in two dimensions over $\mathbb{C}$.  It feels like the complex plane is "embedded" into the scalars and I would like to somehow visualize these planes in the context of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Is there a "good" way to think about this that people find intuitive?

Comment: How do you like to visualize $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: I know that in complex analysis, to visualize a map $f: \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ Riemann surfaces are used. They are hot easy to grasp though. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface

Comment: @Elliott: Are you claiming that these two vector spaces are isomorphic?

Comment: They are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ only.  But no, I was trying to figure out how you visualize 4 spatial dimensions in the first place.

Comment: Not sure if it is useful for OP's purposes, but anyway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two "complex axes" might be visualized as a pair of planes that intersect at a point rather than a line.

Incidentally, the first chapter of Kendig's *Elementary Algebraic Geometry* is devoted to helping visualize hypersurfaces in $\mathbb C^2$.  It has some really great drawings and figures that give a concrete sense of the topology of various algebraic varieties.

Comment: link to the chapter http://academic.csuohio.edu/kendig_k/ag_pdf/ag_chapter_1.pdf